# Retrieving data from server/ Unknown error

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing League of Legends for quite some time now and I never had a problem like this.

Whenever I go into champ select screen, sometimes the program just stops working. It still stays open, music plays, countdown continues, but I cant do a thing. I can't change spells, can't select a champion, and the pick process doesn't continue. Then, when I'm in luck, sometimes after 20 secs or so it comes back, and shows everything updated, like the next picks etc. But until then, my time to select a champ is over and it bugs even more, and I can't do anything again, other than close the client and reopen it.

I lose LP, and I can't join the queue for a lot of time, like 30+ minutes, because this happens constantly. When I'm first pick I might get to pick a champion and lock in and the bug might happen after that, so I wait the time I estimate the pick process would've taken and close the client and reconnect again. I haven't gone through a normal pick process and game in over 10 games.

I also very often get a message in the client, when I'm not in a queue or anything, that says "Unknown error. Sorry about that. We've sent a report to the server". Also, the game crashes when champion select is over and I'm going into the game, saying "The game crashed. Please try to reconnect to the game" and then I have to attempt 2-3 times to reconnect before it actually happens. I also periodically get disconnected from chat. It reconnects after a while, but then disconnects again.

Also, I have trouble joining the queue. It will go on and on for 5-6 minutes, and then I have to exit it and join again, when estimated time is one minute.

I'm not in diamond or anything for it to be normal... I'm Gold trying to go up, but I've fallen an entire division because the champion select screen bug counts as dodging and I lose massive amounts of LP.

Has anyone experienced the same or knows any solutions to this problem?

Here are two screenshots of the error messages I get:

[image: Screenshot]
[image]

Comment: Maybe try to update Adobe Air. The client is written in it I believe. Also, make sure nothing runs in the background that uses for example Flash (youtube, ...). I encounter problems when I am watching youtube videos while the LolClient is running.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically just a server lag where you can't really do anything about it.

I assume you play on NA since the servers are currently experiencing some lag (also because you said you've never experienced something like this before. I'm one of those unlucky EUW players).

Basically the only thing you can do in this time is waiting for the servers to be fixed.

If you are unsure about whether it's your fault or riots, always check the [LoL Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends). These guys are usually just as fast as the official forums. Sometimes they're even faster... If there are any issues, you can see a (usually red) notification on top of the reddit page.

Comment: Holy crap, is that what EUW is like all the time?

Comment: @zpletan well luckily they fixed it now but... yeah about up to 2 months ago it was like that pretty much 4 days per week. And the old EU server before the split... you could say EU players are rather used to it^^^

Comment: Wow. I've never played a 2v2 on SR till today. Glad they fixed it for you!

Comment: If it's a server lag why doesn't everyone experience it and it's just me? And I'm on the EUNE server but if I'm 100% sure that if I change server the problem would be fixed, I would definitely change server as soon as possible. It's really painful to see my LP go by when I'm not even losing.. But I don't want to spent 20 Euro+ to change server and see that nothing is fixed.. Plus that I plan to go to EUW if I change and sadly, I hear lot's of bad comments about that server the last few months.. Including yours.

Comment: @zETO Hmm well usually these messages occur if there are server problems. You can also check the [official forums of your region](forums.leagueoflegends.com/board/) for a 100% official statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've already had this kind of problem, when I wasn't playing on my usual internet connection.

I assumed it was the internet connection that was sometimes disconnecting for some seconds and then LoL client was having trouble to reconnect and took some time to do so (20 sec possibly). Also, when in game, the game would crash just because the internet would be disconnected (still for some seconds only).

In opposition, when I am playing on my usual internet connection, a disconnection of the latter would just result in a "attempt to connect" in LoL, not in a crash.

I can't really explain why my LoL client react differently between internet connection, but the problem might not come from LoL nor from the servers, but maybe from your internet connection?

PS: I don't know if it is a relevant information, but I am playing on Mac.

Comment: Maybe it is indeed just because of my connection since in my country now it's summer and on summer Internet connection is slower overall and more laggy so.. But I don't know if that's the problem for sure since when and if I finally go in game, it never lags or everything. I'm playing normally.. The problem is just on the champion select screen..

Comment: Ok, apart from the connection problem, have you tried to update your computer with windows update? I had this kind of problem too (when I was on pc) and it was just that I was postponing the updating of some stuffs like windows update.

Comment: Never even thought about that but I'll try it. Thanks for the suggestion.